# Is the cone of squares in a Jordan algebra a cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional Jordan algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a finite-dimensional real vector space with a commutative bilinear product $\circ: A \times A \rightarrow A$ satisfying $(a^2 \circ b) \circ a = a^2 \circ (b \circ a)$ for all $a, b \in A$.
Let $Q = \{ a^2 \mid a \in A\}$ be the *cone of squares*.

I want to show: $Q$ is cone (i.e. closed under addition and multiplication with non-negative reals and $Q \cap -Q = \{0\}$).

The only thing I don't know how to show: If $a, b \in Q$, then $a + b = c^2$ for some $c \in Q$. How can I show this?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything about this in McCrimmon's book. Where did you get this question?

Comment: I've seen this claim several times, e.g. in chapter III.2 in "Analysis on Symmetric Cones" by Faraut & Koranyi, or in "Perspectives on the Formalism of Quantum Theory" (http://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/7017), the latter being my primary source of interest.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely this is false for a general Jordan algebra, even finite dimensional over $\mathbb R.$ I downloaded the review of Faraut and Kuranyi by Kenneth Gross, and he emphasizes in a footnote he says:

> What is now called a *symmetric cone* in older terminology was
>   referred to as a *domain of positivity*, and what is now known as a
>   Euclidean Jordan algebra was called a *formally real* Jordan algebra.

Now, from page 3 of McCrimmon's book, we find

> A Jordan algebra is formally real if
>
> $$ x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = 0 
>  \; \Longrightarrow  \; x_1 = \cdots = x_n = 0. $$

This is *A Taste of Jordan Algebras* by Kevin McCrimmon, about 2003.

So, my advice is to see if you can prove your cone property with formal reality as an axiom. As a matter of taste in terminology, I don't see how you can call something a domain of positivity if the sum of strictly positive elements can be zero. If it does not work out, you have several people to ask for a counterexample, that is showing what goes wrong when not formally real.

P S I think you will like the description of Euclidean Jordan algebras in *Newton's Algorithm in Euclidean Jordan Algebras, with Applications to Robotics* by Uwe Helmke, Sandra Ricardo, Shintaro Yoshizawa.

Comment: What with the $>$ between the $=0$ ad the $\implies$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, as long as I tried to keep the Latex as part of the block quote, it insisted on putting those > signs beginning each line of the quote. But since the Latex part is a bit long, that got split over a line, in the end the > became part of the Latex. There is probably some trick for making the whole thing come out right, that is the gray shading including the Latex, but I do not know how. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out. Not a typo in the usual sense.